# There aren't executable/binaries inside the folder lib/x86 of Magisk-v26.1.apk file

Tags: samsung, boot, rom, magisk

I'm trying to enable KVM for SM-A600G (Samsung Galaxy A6 with exynos7870). I'm following [the tutorial by raspiduino](https://github.com/raspiduino/a6lte-kvm):

At point 7:

> Step 7: Download [latest Magisk apk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/) and change the `.apk` extension to `.zip`. Extract zip and look into `lib` here you can find the binary tools for your architecture. On PC you extract `lib/x86/libmagiskboot.so`

Even on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/raspiduino/a6lte-kvm/issues/5) that I've opened:

> Magisk has some native static linked binary for x86 packed inside their apk. Download the magisk's apk, unzip it, look inside `lib/` and you will find some x86 binary. There will be `libmagiskboot.so`. Just run it like a normal Linux executable (`./libmagiskboot.so`)

Ok, I've got the Magisk apk from [here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/download/v26.1/Magisk-v26.1.apk). I've renamed it to zip, and when I looked inside the archive, I've seen that inside the folder `lib/x86` and `lib/x86_64` there aren't executable binaries. Why?

The tutorial on point 8 suggests running `magiskboot`, but I don't have this executable on my disk:

> Step 8: You need to extract the stock `boot.img` from stock rom. You can get stock rom from [samfw.com](https://samfw.com/) or from my release page :). Then use `magiskboot unpack boot.img`, replace stock kernel with our compiled `Image` in `arch/arm64/boot/Image` and repack `boot.img` using `magiskboot repack boot.img new-boot.img`

Where I can get it?

Comment: *"I've seen that inside the folder lib/x86 and lib/x86_64 there aren't executable binaries. Why?"* I just extracted your link and `libmagiskboot.so` executable is there for all four supported architectures.

Comment: I never ran a *.so file. Usually the *.so flles are libraries. So,the so extension is false or what ? Probably it will work even if I run it just like ./libmagiskboot ?

Comment: File extenaion doesn't make a difference. You shouls check the file signature. `libmagiskboot.so` is an executable, not a shared library. `lib*.so` naming convention is a limitation of the APK packaging.

Comment: Ha! didn't know this. I always used [v21.4](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/download/v21.4/Magisk-v21.4.zip) because of this